# Linux with SSH.NET : “sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo”

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, ssh.net

I'm using Renci.SshNet and somehow the remote Linux server is aware that I am not connected using a terminal emulator. So:

```
using Renci.SshNet;

var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("host","username", new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("username", "password"));
using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
client.Connect();

var test = client.RunCommand("sudo mycommand");
```

results in

```
"sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"
```

Question: how to emulate a terminal emulator using SSH.NET ?

The below code that I found on https://refactoragain.com/2016/05/27/ssh-net-echo-sudo-s/ seems to create a terminal emulation :

```
SshClient client = new SshClient(server_address, 22, login, password);
client.Connect();

IDictionary<Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes, uint> modes = 
new Dictionary<Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes, uint>();
termkvp.Add(Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes.ECHO, 53);

ShellStream shellStream = 
sshClient.CreateShellStream("xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024, modes);
var output = shellStream.Expect(new Regex(@"[$>]")); 

shellStream.WriteLine("sudo sh/home/my_user_name/scripts/install_and_configure.sh"); 
output = shellStream.Expect(new Regex(@"([$#>:])"));
shellStream.WriteLine(password);
client.Disconnect();
```

But it's Greek to me as it requires a home directory that I don't seem to have for my username. And why do I have to disconnect? (Last line in the code)

I just want to run Linux commands and get the return string in my code!

A good weekend to all anyway.

Comment: How did you create `client`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably `my command` has `sudo` in it?

`sudo` is interactive, requesting a password, and `RunCommand` doesn't provide anyway to send input to the command.

You need to use `ShellStream` instead.

```
var sh = client.CreateShellStream("", 0, 0, 0, 0);
sh.WriteLine("my command");
sh.WriteLine("sudo password");
```

Comment: Yes. When you telnet/ssh/open a command prompt on Linux, what happens when you type in `my command` (I assume containing sudo) at the prompt?

Comment: When I type sudo mycommand, everything goes ok. It's just that I can't repeat it in C#

Comment: When you type `sudo mycommand`, does it prompt for a password?

Comment: No. Your code seems to work! But only if I step through using F10. Apparently it needs time between each operation (Im creating ftp clients, and the command asks for a user name a password and a quota in separate commands) Is there a way to wait for an answer from the Linux server?

Comment: So: sh.WriteLine("sudo imp_createftp ftptestole5");
                sh.WriteLine("ftptestole5");
                sh.WriteLine("ftptestole5");
                sh.WriteLine("1234"); When I step through slowly it works.